# VideoTexture Crashes iPad

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, video, air, away3d

I'm running a video texture in Away3d in an Adobe Air app which runs fine on desktop and Android, however on iOS it crashes as soon as it tests for VideoTexture support

I create the video as such

```
 sphereGeometry = new SphereGeometry(5000, 64, 48);
        panoTexture2DBase = new NativeVideoTexture(Model.config.getAssetUrl(Model.currentScene.video), true, true);

        panoTexture2DBase.addEventListener(NativeVideoTexture.VIDEO_START,function(e:Event =null){setTimeout(onVideoStart,1000)});
        panoTextureMaterial = new TextureMaterial(panoTexture2DBase, false, false, false);

        panoVideoMesh = new Mesh(sphereGeometry, panoTextureMaterial);
        panoVideoMesh.scaleX *= -1;

        panoVideoMesh.rotate(Vector3D.Y_AXIS,-90);

        scene.addChild(panoVideoMesh);
        view.render();

        panoTexture2DBase.player.pause();
```

And the iPad appears to crash as soon as it plays

```
            _player.play();
```

In NativeVideoClass

Does anyone know how to stop the iPad crashing when I try and use VideoTexture or is this doomed to failiure?

This is the Air 21.

I've tried taking the video out of Away3d and into Starling. I've changed the codecs and managed to get it running in Starling.

The same video is still crashing in Away3D tho. It's when it's gets added to the stage.

I'm also getting NetStream.Play.Failed in the netstats event before it fails.

The crash report

```
   Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000d8
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
    63.498324    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c53a30 TCP Conn 0x12955be00 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
    63.499758    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c54f5c TCP Conn 0x12955be00 event 1. err: 0
    63.776992    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c55034 TCP Conn 0x12955be00 started
    65.311738    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c53a30 TCP Conn 0x1275da440 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
    65.312713    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c54f5c TCP Conn 0x1275da440 event 1. err: 0
    65.561496    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c55034 TCP Conn 0x1275da440 started
    65.824002    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c53a30 TCP Conn 0x1275d7370 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
    65.825093    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c54f5c TCP Conn 0x1275d7370 event 1. err: 0
    66.092512    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c55034 TCP Conn 0x1275d7370 started
    66.434776    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184bb1a18 TCP Conn 0x12756c8a0 SSL Handshake DONE
    67.267381    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184bb1928 TCP Conn 0x12756c8a0 starting SSL negotiation
    67.268033    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c53a30 TCP Conn 0x12756c8a0 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
    67.268518    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c54f5c TCP Conn 0x12756c8a0 event 1. err: 0
    67.642271    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184c55034 TCP Conn 0x12756c8a0 started
    67.648583    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184caa608 Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
    67.648583    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184caa5d4 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    67.648583    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184cfc394 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   Video Test                      0x000000010042d52c 0x1000b0000 + 3659052
    1   Video Test                      0x0000000100187688 0x1000b0000 + 882312
    2   Video Test                      0x0000000100182b94 0x1000b0000 + 863124
    3   Video Test                      0x0000000100182ab0 0x1000b0000 + 862896
    4   Video Test                      0x000000010042bfb4 0x1000b0000 + 3653556
    5   Video Test                      0x0000000100185ec0 0x1000b0000 + 876224
    6   Video Test                      0x00000001000c3f78 0x1000b0000 + 81784
    7   UIKit                           0x000000018aaaf014 0x18aa2c000 + 536596
    8   UIKit                           0x000000018ace9adc 0x18aa2c000 + 2874076
    9   FrontBoardServices              0x000000018f0ecb68 0x18f0d4000 + 101224
    10  Foundation                      0x00000001863b6098 0x186300000 + 745624
    11  BaseBoard                       0x000000018c94f704 0x18c92c000 + 145156
    12  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018f0e7bb8 0x18f0d4000 + 80824
    13  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018f0ec940 0x18f0d4000 + 100672
    14  UIKit                           0x000000018aceaef4 0x18aa2c000 + 2879220
    15  UIKit                           0x000000018aceab9c 0x18aa2c000 + 2878364
    16  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018f0fb7c4 0x18f0d4000 + 161732
    17  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018f0fbb44 0x18f0d4000 + 162628
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185468544 0x18538c000 + 902468
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185467fd8 0x18538c000 + 901080
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185465cd8 0x18538c000 + 892120
    21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185394ca0 0x18538c000 + 36000
    22  GraphicsServices                0x00000001903fc088 0x1903f0000 + 49288
    23  UIKit                           0x000000018aaacffc 0x18aa2c000 + 528380
    24  Video Test                      0x00000001001a02e8 0x1000b0000 + 983784
    25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019a8428b8 0x19a840000 + 10424
```

Comment: Which version of Air? Away3d? Have you tried a non-Away3d (using Stage3D api directly) based VideoTexture to see if it is a Air version "?" runtime bug on iOS? Tried other versions of Air?

Comment: Did you try a video file (mp4) that has been known to play fine on iOS? Or record a short test clip with iPad camera and try that as a video texture. This issue could be anything from video's settings to a bad line of code that iPad doesn't like. Also `Exception Message` tells you the limit on resource usage per app was **exceeded**. It is `150 per sec` but your crashed app gives `1617 per sec` for over 300 secs (5 mins) of usage... So check into why the big memory spike once your video texture is involved.

Comment: Yes it's Air 21. I'll try other versions of Air and try some other videos - and try to work out what the memory spike is about if it's not just trying to load a video.

Comment: Was your Starling test equal to the Away3D scene? Like are they both one  sphere with an MP4 video texture, and you're saying Starling works whilst Away3D crashes when you do that? So you changed the codecs from what to what? In your video editor/converter, re-export the MP4 file containing H.264 video & choose to encode at a "Baseline" profile during file save settings. Try a smaller resolution if still problems. Try enable / disable hardware acceleration in your app settings..